# Link Username To Post Created By User

Tags: python, django, authentication

I would like to link the user who created the post by their username that way people know who it was posted by but I can't seem to get it to work and yes I am logged in and I have a working register and login form already.

Every time I go to submit some news from the form when logged in I get this error `NOT NULL constraint failed: news_news.author_id`

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField
from markdownx.utils import markdownify
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class News(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    short_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = MarkdownxField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, News
from .forms import NewNewsForm
from django.shortcuts import render

def show_news_view(request):
    news = News.objects.values('author', 'title', 'short_desc', 'tags', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

    context = {
        'news': news
    }
    return render(request, "news/news_home.html", context)

def new_news_form_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewNewsForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = NewNewsForm()

            return redirect('/news')
    else:
        form = NewNewsForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "news/news_form.html", context)
```

EDIT:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import News

class NewNewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ['title', 'short_desc', 'content', 'category', 'tags', 'slug']
```

news_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% else %}
    <p>Please login before you can submit a news story.</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `NewNewsForm()` it looks as if you aren't setting the attribute before save

Comment: The form worked before I tested it then I went to add the author field to it now I get the error I mentioned in the post. @ViaTech

Comment: @Brain wait a sec... `fields = ['title', 'short_desc', 'content', 'category', 'tags', 'slug']` in your model form does not have `author_id` this is your issue and it is why you are obviously getting the error... If you post your `News` model too it will likely show that field is required, thus the error. Quickly speaking, after `form.isValid()` assign the `author_id` to the object and then save it and your error should be gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the user.

*Later edit with a simpler solution:*

Simply pass `commit=False` when saving the form. Which will create your `News` object without commiting it to DB. Simply set the author afterwards and save the object.

```
def new_news_form_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_data = request.POST or None
        form = NewNewsForm(form_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            news = form.save(commit=False)
            news.author = request.user
            news.save()
            return redirect('/news')
    else:
        form = NewNewsForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "news/news_form.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you but I get this error: `name 'user' is not defined` also where do I add the last bit of code to my forms.py or views.py file?

Comment: Last bit of code goes in your forms.py. Where do you get that error?

Comment: Ok thats what I thought but the error shows after the form is submitted

Comment: @Brian just updated my answer with a simpler solution. I think this will solve your problems.